# Run a Kubernetes pod with IAM role permissions

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam

I'm evaluating Kubernetes as a replacement for our ECS setup. Is it possible to run a pod as an IAM role, similar to the ECS task role? I'd like to create roles for each service that needs AWS API accessbut I haven't found a good solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam#readme)? There's another similar project, but I'd only want to dig up the URL if you haven't already tried those solutions.